# Does this inversion take any effect, "Knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts, Snape."?

Tags: sentence-construction, inversion

> Oh, you know Quirrell already, do you? No wonder he's looking so nervous, that's Professor Snape. He teaches Potions, but he doesn't want to -- everyone knows he's after Quirrell's job. **Knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts, Snape**."

I think the normal order of the sentence in bold is: *Snape knows an awful lot about the Dark Arts*. I'm wondering if there are any literary effect for that inversion?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's not called an inversion but has some other name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more common in UK English than US English. At least, that's the only place I hear this grammatical pattern--it seems to be associated with uneducated UK English speakers, in particular (in movies).  Perhaps some UK readers can chime in to verify. Certainly if I heard it, I would likely wonder whether the speaker was foreign or imitating a foreigner.

I can imagine hearing this, but not with someone's name. More like a reference to them (and it would be informal/colloquial).

> She's quite the looker, that one.

Still sounds British to me, or perhaps a yokel dialect I don't hear much.